# Media Encoder - H.264 with CRF setting?

Tags: h.264, mencoder, adobe-after-effects

I have recently started using Adobe After Effects and use **Adobe Media Encoder** to render my H.264 videos (with Quicktime installed).
I am familiar with ffmpeg and have always been using **CRF based encoding** with x264/x265 but I do not see this setting in Adobe Media Encoder - only CBR and VBR 1/2 pass. Does it only allow for VBR with min/max bitrate set up?
What am I missing?
Thank you so much!